# Count values with after close window javascript

Tags: javascript, count, popup, alert

I have images:

```
<img src="">
<img src="">
<img src="">
```

I need add same data i don't know how to add name="1" or name="0" or something similar. And if I close window show me alert with return to same page and information counted if name ==0 show alert.

Comment: You need to give us some more code and please be specific when you are trying to explain something...I really don't understand what you need

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps you can edit and add a sample of what you want the final result to look like

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].name="0";
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[1].name="2";
.
.
```

OR

with jQuery

```
$('img').each(function(){
    this.name=this.indexOf();
}
$(window).on('unload',function(){
    alert("Watevr you want");
}
```

Comment: I have images <img src="" class="abc"> how to count how much are images with this class? var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('.aaa');

                alert(elems.length);

Comment: If its a new question, please ask on another thread. And close this thread if your problem was solved by selecting an answer. And yes that could work. Just don't specify the '.' before the classname.